# Please explain how my DbContext is being instantiate?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

About 3 years ago I build a Web API and created a generic repository with Ninject for DI.  Today I'm reviewing my code to make some changes and I can't understand where my DbContext is being instantiated. I can't remember what I didn't, I believe this was a hybrid of a bunch of implementation I reading up on Generic Repo.

I've spent quite some time reading through documentation online but couldn't find an answer. Can someone please explain it to me so I can document it properly?  Below is my sample generic repo, application repo, my controller and Ninject binding.  I know in .net core you can inject it from the startup but this was web api 2 using EF6.

Generic Repo:

```
public GenericRepository(DbContext _context, ILogService _log)
{
   this.context = _context;
   entities = context.Set<T>();      
}
```

Entity Repo:

```
public ApplicationRepository(TransactionDbContext context) : base(context)
{

}
```

Controller:

```
public ApplicationController(IApplicationRepository _applicationRepository)
{
   this.applicationRepository = _applicationRepository
}
```

Ninject Binding:
`kernel.Bind<IApplicationRepository>().To<ApplicationRepository>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Ninject allows you to auto-resolve concrete types.

For more information, you can read the Ninject wiki: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-With-Ninject

Comment: I know what Ninject does but I'm asking how is the DbContext instantiate? Nowhere in my code have any auto-resolve for the DbContext.

Comment: As I understand, the GenericRepository is instantiated with Ninject. When Ninject is trying to resolve it, all dependencies in the GenericRepository constructor also will be resolved even you didn't bind them before. But, only concrete types can be resolved without bindings.

Comment: Thank you, Aleksey.  That is what was confusing me. If Ninject is resolving the DbContext which is a concrete class.